# Apeend jQuery element with dynamic PHP code in it

Tags: php, jquery

I want to append 100 of span element which should contain dynamic php code inside it to fetch data from wordpress database. I am trying the following code, but it is not working out for me, please give me some suggestions.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var i = 1;
  while (i <= 100) {
    $(".peak").append("<span class='<?php echo $result[0]-column"+i+";?>'><?php echo $result[0]->column"+i+";?><span>");
    i++;
  }
});
```

Output should be,

```
<span class='column1[data]'>column1[data]</span>

<span class='column2[data]'>column2[data]</span>

<span class='column3[data]'>column3[data]</span>
```

and so on...

This code is working perfect if I remove `i` increment:

```js
  var i = 1;
  while (i <= 100) {
    $(".peak").append("<span class='<?php echo $result[0]->column1;?>'><?php echo $result[0]->column1;?></span>");
    i++;
  }
```

Comment: Hi Rahul! The problem is: PHP is a server-side language and JS a client-side language. So PHP got executed before JS. For your problem you need to take a look at AJAX with JS or jQuery.

Comment: Okay, can you please suggest me how can I complete this using Ajax, or similar kind of some post from where I can get some idea. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can try to display the data using php:

```
<?php

$result = [ // get result from db;
  0 => [
    "column1" => [
      "data" => "a"
    ],
    "column2" => [
      "data" => "b"
    ],
    "column3" => [
      "data" => "c"
    ],
  ]
];

echo "<div class=\"peak\">\n";
  foreach ($result[0] as $key => $value) {
    echo "\t<span class=\"$value[data]\">$value[data]<span>\n";
} 
echo "</div>\n";
```

output:

```
<div class="peak">
  <span class="a">a<span>
  <span class="b">b<span>
  <span class="c">c<span>
</div>
```

Second way by AJAX `index.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .peak span {
      margin-right: 5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="peak">
  <span>loading...</span>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $.ajax({
      url: '/get_data.php',
      method: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(result){
        $('.peak').empty() //  remove children (span 'loading...')    

      // next forEach extract key as "column$i" 
      // and value as [ data=> a] etc. in php 
      Object.entries(result[0]).forEach(([key, value]) => {
          //next line get value.data or (result[0].column$i[data] in php)
          const {data} = value;
          const span = $('<span />').attr('class', data).html(data);
          $('.peak').append(span);
        })
      }
    });
  })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and `mock` for example `get_data.php`:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$result = [
  0 => [
    "column1" => [
      "data" => "a"
    ],
    "column2" => [
      "data" => "b"
    ],
    "column3" => [
      "data" => "c"
    ],
  ]
];

echo json_encode($result);
```